# How to parse texts separated by line breaks

Tags: python, nlp

How can I parse tokens separated by line break such as the one below:

```
Wolff PERSON
is O
in O    
Argentina LOCATION

The O
US LOCATION
Envoy O 
noted O
```

into full sentences like this using python?

```
Wolff is in Argentina
The US Envoy noted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = '''Wolff PERSON
is O
in O    
Argentina LOCATION

The O
US LOCATION
Envoy O 
noted O'''
>>> c = StringIO(s)
>>> for k, g in groupby(c, key=str.isspace):
    if not k:
        print ' '.join(x.split(None, 1)[0] for x in g)
...         
Wolff is in Argentina
The US Envoy noted
```

If input is actually coming from a string rather than a file, then:

```
for k, g in groupby(s.splitlines(), key= lambda x: not x.strip()):
    if not k:
        print ' '.join(x.split(None, 1)[0] for x in g)
...         
Wolff is in Argentina
The US Envoy noted
```

Comment: Wouldn't `c = s.splitlines()` been sufficient, instead of making a StringIO?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I thought OP's input is going to come from a file, that's why used StringIO. No, this code will not work for `str.splitlines`, as it strips the trailing `\n`, i.e resulting in empty string and that will fail the `str.isspace` condition.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary, thank you. Please could you explain what this line does ? `' '.join(x.split(None, 1)[0] for x in g)`

Comment: @DevEx Here `g` is the grouper object containing the lines of the current group, and then we loop over each line in the group split it only once at whitespace and just store the first word. Later join those words using a space.

Comment: I tried this `f = open("file.txt", "r")
reader = f.readlines()
c = StringIO(reader)
for k, g in groupby(c, key=str.isspace):
    if not k:
        print ' '.join(x.split(None, 1)[0] for x in g)` but its not working. Please what am I doing wrongly?

Comment: @DevEx Simply pass `f` to groupby: `for k, g in groupby(f, key=str.isspace)`

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary, I added one more column to represent the predictions. How can I use this technique to find out sentences with wrong predictions based on the 2nd and 3rd column ?  [link](http://tny.cz/60d11ab1)

Comment: @DevEx Please post it as a new question I'll try to answer it there.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary, thanks I have just posted it [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107142/read-through-sentences-separated-by-line-break-and-parse)