# read through sentences separated by line break and parse

Tags: python

Given that I have tokenized sentences separated with a linebreak, and I have 2 columns representing the actual and predicted tag for the tokens. I want to loop through each of these token and find out wrong predictions e.g. actual tag not equal to predicted tag

```
#word actual predicted

James PERSON PERSON
Washington PERSON LOCATION     
went O O
home O LOCATION

He O O
took O O
Elsie PERSON PERSON
along O O

>James Washington went home: Incorrect
>He took Elsie along: Correct
```

Comment: I know of `itertools.groupby` but I dont know how I can apply it in this case

Comment: If any of the predicted output is not equal to actual output then you want to print `Incorrect`?

Comment: exactly. if actual is not equal to predicted, then print incorrect and if otherwise equal, print correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23084050/846892) I am using [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) and a list comprehension here:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = {True: 'Correct', False: 'Incorrect'}
with open('text1.txt') as f:
    for k, g in groupby(f, key=str.isspace):
        if not k:
            # Split each line in the current group at whitespaces
            data = [line.split() for line in g] 
            # If for each line the second column is equal to third then `all()` will
            # return True.
            predicts_matched = all(line[1] == line[2] for line in data)
            print ('{}: {}'.format(' '.join(x[0] for x in data), d[predicts_matched]))
```

**Output:**

```
James Washington went home: Incorrect
He took Elsie along: Correct
```

Answer (score 0):

Python strings have powerful parsing functions you can use here.  I did this using Python 3.3, but it should work with any other version as well.

```
thistext = '''James PERSON PERSON
Washington PERSON LOCATION     
went O O
home O LOCATION

He O O
took O O
Elsie PERSON PERSON
along O O
'''

def check_text(text):
    lines = text.split('\n')
    correct = [True] #a bool wrapped in a list,we can modify it from a nested function
    words = []

    def print_result():
        if words:
            print( ' '.join(words), ": ", "Correct" if correct[0] else "Incorrect" )
        #words.clear()
        del words[:]        
        correct[0] = True

    for line in lines:
        if line.strip():  # check if the line is empty
            word, a, b = line.split()
            if a != b:
                correct[0] = False
            words.append(word)
        else:
            print_result();

    print_result()

check_text(thistext)
```